# Packaging problems with PPA's from the user perspective are on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

One of the issues I find from time to time are packages dependencies problems related with PPA's due careless package maintainers. These problems are normally fixed changing one line ([or several one lines](https://askubuntu.com/a/477646/169736)) in the package, which needs to be addressed by the PPA maintainers.

Now, I know that if these problems happened [with Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1262022) (I've already submitted a patch to that one), [or Debian for what matters](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=746034), packages I these would be threated as bug report, as they are bug reports. The problem with PPA's is, that they don't have bug trackers in LaunchPad (or at least is not so obvious) so you have to contact the maintainer of the PPA's so they can fix their stuff. Now here comes my problem, whenever I address (or answer) these problems they lose value once they are fixed, since nobody should have the same issue again (which happens with the bug reports).

So, are these issues really on the scope of the site. I really don't care anymore (through I would love the package maintainers re-read the [Debian Maintainers Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)) since I try to answer them from the package maintainer perspective, but I want to know if I can spend my time answering them without problem.

Answer (score -3):

The answer should be generic yet informative.

Example: "This PPA is currently not bring properly maintained.  Please check back later to see if the PPA is up and current.  The owner should have been emailed to be reminded that it is their duty to keep up with it."

This isn't exactly how I would word it, but the idea comes across the same.

Also making a flag specific too this case should be made.

Comment: That's as bad as it could get. That's not an answer and not a good comment either (just imo). When one has already established the cause of the problem, I would prefer one to provide a solution instead of that unhelpful chattering if the question is to be kept open.

Comment: The problem is how to handle it, I am giving a suggested idea that could work.  I did mention that the suggested answer wasn't exactly like the one I gave.  The problem of a solution is that it isn't up to us.  Had you read Braiam's actually post word for word, you would noticed he was seeking a way for people to understand that it is up to the people who made the PPA to maintenance and keep it up to date.  It not our issue that it isn't behind.